# Add _timestamp to Elasticsearch results using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index which has `_timestamp` populated on every record. Using Marvel or curl I can get the `_timestamp` in the "fields" part of the result for example:

```
GET index/type/_search?fields=_timestamp,_source
{
   "took": 11,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 3,
      "successful": 3,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 116888,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "index",
            "_type": "type",
            "_id": "mXJdWqSLSfykbMtChiCRjA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "results": "example",
            },
            "fields": {
               "_timestamp": 1443618319514
            }
         },...
```

However when doing a search using the Java API I cant get it to return the `_timestamp`.

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder= client.prepareSearch(index)
            .addFacet(facet)
            .setFrom(start)
            .setSize(limit);
SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();
```

Can anyone tell me how to ask for `_timestamp` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use the `setFields()` method like this:

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder= client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setType(type)
            .addFacet(facet)
            .setFields("_timestamp")          <--- add this line
            .setFrom(start)
            .setSize(limit);
SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: .setFields is not an available method in my version of ES however I used addFields instead and it still did not return the timestamp. Any other ideas?

`SearchRequestBuilder buider = client.prepareSearch(index)
    .addFacet(facet)
    .addFields("_timestamp", "_source")
    .setFrom(start)
    .setSize(limit);
   return builder;`

Comment: And what version is that?

Comment: Elasticsearch version 1.1.1.
When I added .addFields('_timestamp') then the source disappeared. But when I used .addFields("timestamp", "_source") the source returns again but still no time stamp, even though it is being stored.

Comment: 1.1.1, ouch :) It's weird, though, because I could find the [`setFields` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/get/GetRequestBuilder.java#L93) in the 1.1.1 release.

Comment: Unfortunately 1.1.1 :( Yes but that is for the GetRequestBuilder whereas im using the [SearchRequestBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/cf3e92ae92356e5225bce1ced3e6e612ac850b3c/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.java)

Comment: My bad, then [`addFields()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.java#L538) should work the way I see it. What error do you get (if any)?

Comment: `{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 186413,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "mXJdWqSLSfykbMtChiCRjA",
      "_score" : 1.0, 
      "_source" : {"EXAMPLE:DATA"}
    }, {...`

No error, just no timestamp :(

Comment: How do you print out your results from the `response` variable?

Comment: Ahh i figured it out thanks to your help :) 
I wasnt specifying the type, seems to be required for the timestamp for some reason. I added this line `.setSearchType("type")`